# Why is the color of <a> not changing when href="#"?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a style for my links, but it works only with external websites. For example :

```
<a class='optionLink' href='deletelink.php?url=" . urlencode($url) . "'>Supprimer</a>

<a href='#' class='optionLink' onClick=\"showEditForm('" . $url . "', '" . str_ireplace('&quot;', '\&quot;', str_ireplace("&apos;", "\&apos;", $name)) . "');\">Modifier</a>

<a href='" . $url . "'>" . $name . "</a><br /><br />
```

And my style is

```
.optionLink{
    background:#0AC986;
    /*display:inline-block;*/
    font-size:16px;
    height:35px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:none;
    padding: 10px 3px 10px 3px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    font-family: 'open_sanslight';
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
}
```

```css
.optionLink{
    background:#0AC986;
    /*display:inline-block;*/
    font-size:16px;
    height:35px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:none;
    padding: 10px 3px 10px 3px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    font-family: 'open_sanslight';
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<a class='optionLink' href='deletelink.php?url=" . urlencode($url) . "'>Supprimer</a> <a href='#' class='optionLink' onClick=\"showEditForm('" . $url . "', '" . str_ireplace('&quot;', '\&quot;', str_ireplace("&apos;", "\&apos;", $name)) . "');\">Modifier</a> <a href='" . $url . "'>" . $name . "</a><br /><br />
```

But the color is only white with the first link, the one with the # is still black.

Anyone has an idea of why / how to resolve this ?

Thanks

Comment: But my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jf5be73j/ tells me a different story

Comment: Make a fiddle to illustrate your problem

Comment: I see html markup is not well formatted.

Comment: Please post more css code that's related to this. It seems this issue can be solved easily if you inspect the html

Comment: Problem solved, :visited forgot problem... Sorry :s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you by any chance have something like this:

```
a:visited {
    color:#000;
}
```

if so, you'll need to define your `:visited` part of `.optionLink`

i.e:

```
.optionLink:visited {
    color:#fff;
}
```

The reason this happens is because once you've clicked that link, although it's a dummy link going no-where it now acts as if it's been visited.

Comment: Sometimes I just feel like slapping myself. Well done, my problem was that. Thanks a lot dude.

Comment: no worries @ThomasPatKowalski-Zuckerberg happens to the best of us